# PercolateException[failed to percolate]; nested - Percolate API on nested document

Tags: elasticsearch, nested

I am using elasticsearch 1.1.

Normally in this version, percolator on nested documents should work.

Although, i am trying to do this but I get the following error:

```
failures: [

    {
        index: test
        shard: 4
        reason: BroadcastShardOperationFailedException[[test][4] ]; nested: PercolateException[failed to percolate]; nested: ElasticsearchIllegalArgumentException[Nothing to percolate]; 
    }

]
```

I have the following percolator (sorry elasticsearch head removed me all the quotes):

```
{

    _index: test
    _type: .percolator
    _id: 27
    _version: 1
    _score: 1
    _source: {
        query: {
            filtered: {
                query: {
                    match_all: { }
                }
                filter: {
                    nested: {
                        filter: {
                            term: {
                                city: london
                            }
                        }
                        path: location
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

And while trying to percolate this document I am getting the error:

```
{
  ...
  "location": {
    "date": "2014-05-05T15:07:58",
    "namedplaces": {
      "city": "london"
    }
  }
}
```

Any idea why it doesn't work ?

**EDIT :**

In elasticsearch log I got more precision about the error:

```
[2014-05-06 13:33:48,972][DEBUG][action.percolate         ] [Tomazooma] [test][2], node[H42BBxajRs2w2NmllMnp7g], [P], s[STARTED]: Failed to execute [org.elasticsearch.action.percolate.PercolateReque
st@7399452e]
org.elasticsearch.percolator.PercolateException: failed to percolate
        at org.elasticsearch.action.percolate.TransportPercolateAction.shardOperation(TransportPercolateAction.java:198)
        at org.elasticsearch.action.percolate.TransportPercolateAction.shardOperation(TransportPercolateAction.java:55)
        at org.elasticsearch.action.support.broadcast.TransportBroadcastOperationAction$AsyncBroadcastAction$2.run(TransportBroadcastOperationAction.java:226)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchIllegalArgumentException: Nothing to percolate
        at org.elasticsearch.percolator.PercolatorService.percolate(PercolatorService.java:187)
        at org.elasticsearch.action.percolate.TransportPercolateAction.shardOperation(TransportPercolateAction.java:194)
        ... 5 more
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documentation of ES is not really clear about it. But when you look at [this page](http://www.elasticsearch.org/blog/percolator/), you will see that when you are percolating you need to surround your indexed document by doc{}. It is indeed compulsory otherwise the exception that you've got will appears:

Try to do so on :

```
   {
"doc":{
  ...
  "location": {
    "date": "2014-05-05T15:07:58",
    "namedplaces": {
      "city": "london"
    }
  }
}
}
```

I hope it will help ;-)

Comment: Thanks that was the solution

Comment: Hi asimov, could you explicit your problem with a new question. Provide mapping, request and answer ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Another reason for the `Nothing to percolate` exception is not setting the `Content-Length` HTTP header.

Because the GET request has a body, it should also have a 'Content-Length' HTTP header, but not all APIs will set this for you; as I found out the hard way!